# JSON ISO8601 parsing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, iso8601

Still learning the nuances of JavaScript date handling with what **looks** like a bug somewhere.

Returning records from C# using .ToUniversalTime()... works like a charm, however, JavaScript balks at some of the date/time coming back.

The good: 2012-12-14T21:25:44.273Z toLocaleTimeString() returns 2:25:44 PM

the bad: 2012-12-14T21:25:44.18Z returns Invalid Date

the ugly: what with the .18Z at the end... should it have been .018Z or .180Z?  And, is it a C# bug or a JavaScript bug?

Comment: Will you always have times ending with `Z` or could there be other timezones (e.g. `-10:00`)?

Comment: Which browsers or other environments are you trying for JavaScript? Both examples work fine in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/veHEk/.

Comment: I ran that in Chrome and yup, an IE9 bug (or no feature) looks like.  2nd result shows NaN.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The discrepancy may not be a bug as much as competing standards. [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) specifies that milliseconds be formatted "*as three decimal digits*" -- http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.15. W3C, however, specifies them as "*one or more digits*" -- http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime. So, `.180Z` would satisfy both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is an IE9 bug, and it does work in IE10.  However, you can use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to make this work consistently cross-browser, and yes - it does work in IE9.

```
// This works in IE10 and Chrome, fails in IE9
alert(new Date("2012-12-14T21:25:44.18Z"));


// This works everywhere
alert(moment("2012-12-14T21:25:44.18Z"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.parse` to parse ISO-8601 datetime.